# Continuing an if/else statement with a string(yes or no)

Tags: java, if-statement

```
// SquaresIn program 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class AreaInv2{

 public static void main (String[] args)
 { 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println ("Hi there! What's your name?"); 
  String name = sc.next();

  System.out.println("Alright , " + name + ", enter the radius of the circle:");
  float radius = sc.nextFloat();

  float area = (float)(Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
  System.out.print("The area is ");
  System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
  System.out.println(". Would you like the area of any other circles?");

  String yesno;
  yesno = sc.next();
  {
      if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
          {
              System.out.println("Alright , " + name + ", enter the radius of the circle:");
              radius = sc.nextFloat();

              area = (float)(Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
              System.out.print("The area is ");
              System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
              System.out.print(" square units.");
              System.out.println(" Would you like the area of any other circles?");
          }
      else if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
          {
              System.out.print("Have a great day " + name + "!");
              sc.close();

          }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Sorry, could you say yes or no?");
          yesno = sc.next();
          if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
          {
              System.out.println("Alright , " + name + ", enter the radius of the circle:");
              radius = sc.nextFloat();

              area = (float)(Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
              System.out.print("The area is ");
              System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
              System.out.print(" square units.");
              System.out.println(" Would you like the area of any other circles?");
          }
      else if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
          {
              System.out.print("Have a great day " + name + "!");
              sc.close();
      }
      }   
  }
 }
}
```

Hello, I just started programming in Java and even after much research I cannot seem to figure out how to do this in a way I understand. Currently when someone responds to "Would you like the area of any other circles" there are three options: A) yes B) no C) anything. When you answer "no" it works perfectly. When you put in random characters, it asks you to say yes or no at which point answering no works fine but similar to A when I answer yes, it goes up to the point where it finds the area of the circle and asks if you would like the area of other circles. This is where I would like to find out if I can make it so that the program goes on forever until the user enters "no". It would be really helpful if someone could check this out and tell me what I can do, keep in mind my knowledge of Java is very little. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the help, I called up a friend of mine and he explained everything to me. I appreciate what you guys did for me :)

Comment: Read up on do-while loops.  Or try searching here.  Questions very similar to this have been asked many times.

Comment: you need to make use of loops here, in your case its better using do-while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to run as long as a given condition is met, then you have to use loops. In Java, we have three types of loops, the do-while loop, while loop, and for loop.

In your case you should use do-while since you need to run it at least once before checking the condition.

Please try the following code, and hopefully it'll help you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaInv2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hi there! What's your name?");
        String name = sc.next();
        String yesno;
        do {
            System.out.println("Alright , " + name + ", enter the radius of the circle:");
            float radius = sc.nextFloat();   
            float area = (float) (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);

            System.out.print("The area is ");
            System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
            System.out.println(". Would you like the area of any other circles?");
            yesno = sc.next();

            while ((!(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no")))) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, could you say yes or no?");
                yesno = sc.next();
            }
        } while (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

        System.out.print("Have a great day " + name + "!");
        sc.close();                
    }
}
```

It's pretty much the same as your code, I just added the loops, and put your condition there.

Comment: Hi this is the only code of the bunch of people that have responded that I actually can somewhat understand. Could you explain the

 while ((!(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no")))) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, could you say yes or no?");
                yesno = sc.next();
part? what do the || mean as well as the exclamation mark?

Comment: and does do (block of code) while yesno = yes just say to keep looping that section as long as they answer?

Comment: update: I just called up a friend and asked him to explain the code that you wrote out and now I understand it! Thanks!

Comment: @gmitra, Hey, apologies for not being able to reply yesterday. I wasn't online. Anyways, I'm happy it worked for you. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `do {} while` and simplify your code with something like -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Hi there! What's your name?");
String name = sc.next();

String yesno = null;
do {
    System.out.printf("Alright %s, enter the radius of the circle: ",
            name);

    float radius = sc.nextFloat();
    float area = (float) (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
    System.out.printf("The area is %.2f. Would you like "
            + "the area of any other circles?", area);
    yesno = sc.next();
    while (!yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
            && !yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, could you please say yes or no?");
        yesno = sc.next();
    }
} while (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
System.out.printf("Have a great day %s!%n", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to organize your code in reusable function to make it more readable:

```
public class AreaInv2 {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = getName();
        while (true) {
            float radius = getRadius(name);
            printArea(radius);
            System.out.println("Would you like the area of any other circles? ");
            if (!needToDoAgain()) {
                System.out.print("Have a great day " + name + "!");
                break;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    private static String getName() {
        System.out.println("Hi there! What's your name?");
        return sc.next();
    }

    private static float getRadius(String name) {
        System.out.println("Alright , " + name + ", enter the radius of the circle: ");
        return sc.nextFloat();
    }

    private static void printArea(float radius) {
        float area = (float) (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
        System.out.print("The area is ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
        System.out.println(".");
    }

    private static boolean needToDoAgain() {
        String yesno = sc.next();
        if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            return true;
        } else if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, could you say yes or no? ");
            return needToDoAgain();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're doing methods, why not make the `name` an instance variable, so that you're not passing it to your methods. `getRadius(String name)` doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: @J.Lucky you right but name isn't really an instance variable. in this case program get the name once but it may change to get name in every loop iteration...

Comment: An interesting use of recursion in place of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if you want something continues (not end) until some specific condition happens, you should use loop. `while`, `do while`,`for` are three approaches in java.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hi there! What's your name?");
        String name = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Alright , " + name
                + ", enter the radius of the circle:");
        float radius = sc.nextFloat();

        float area = (float) (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
        System.out.print("The area is ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
        System.out.println(". Would you like the area of any other circles?");
        String yesno = null;

        yesno = sc.next();

        while (!yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

            if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                System.out.printf(
                        "Alright %s, enter the radius of the circle: ", name);

                radius = sc.nextFloat();
                area = (float) (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
                System.out.printf("The area is %.2f. Would you like "
                        + "the area of any other circles?", area);

            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry, could you please say yes or no?");
            }
            yesno = sc.next();
        }

        sc.close();

        System.out.printf("Have a great day %s!%n", name);
```